# Visual Studio 2008 C++ Command Line Option for '-mwindows' (from MinGW)

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2008, mingw

I have been using MinGW for a while to compile programs but decided that I should use an IDE and got Visual Studio 2008 Express Edition. In MinGW whenever I created a OpenGL program or a windows program, I used to command line option "-mwindows" so that when I ran the .exe the actual program would run and not also display a command prompt. So I am wondering what is the equivalent of `-mwindows` for Visual Studio 2008?

Comment: Pick the right project template.  Win32 Console app for a console app, Win32 Project for a native Windows app.  The setting that's different between the two is Linker + System + SubSystem.  And main() vs WinMain() for the entrypoint.